# Java ProcessBuilder running in specific directory

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

How can i start a process using processbuilder in a specific directory?

thanks!

Comment: Look at the Javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into this method in the `ProcessBuilder` class.

```
directory(File directory)
```

This method sets the directory for the `ProcessBuilder`. The Javadoc can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29).